# Efficient way to slice ByteBuffer and append data to it

Tags: java, performance, nio, bytebuffer

I have an existing ByeBuffer backed by an array. Now I want to get a portion of this ByteBuffer from an offset to the end and then append some data (stored in other byte array) to the end of this sliced ByteBuffer. Assuming I have "offset" in the ByteBuffer and byte array "buffer" which needs to be appended to the ByteBuffer. This is what I am doing now -

```
                byte[] prevArray = previousByteBuffer.array();

                byte[] newArray = new byte[prevArray.length-offset+buffer.length];
                for(int i=offset; i<prevArray.length; i++){
                    newArray[i-offset] = prevArray[i];
                }
                for(int i=prevArray.length; i<(prevArray.length+len); i++){
                    newArray[i-offset] = buffer[i-prevArray.length];
                }
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(newArray);
```

I think what I am doing is highly inefficient. What's the efficient way to achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: Classic XY problem. What is the actual task you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @EJP The actual scenario is that I am writing a function which will read a range of bytes from a file and this range is input to my function. Each time the function is invoked I check the range to see if its overlapping with the last data I read, if yes I don't want to reread the overlapping data. Hence, slice and append.

Comment: I suggest that it would be faster *not* to do this. Let the file system do the caching. It's *really* good at this. Or use a `MappedByteBuffer,` if the file isn't enormous. I also draw your attention to the [`ByteBuffer.slice()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice()) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you could do is preallocate your eventual ByteBuffer as large as practical. arraycopy will help, but the what's killing you is re-copying of the original data. If you can use some heuristic to better predict your eventual destination size, you can avoid recopying of data, and speed the entire thing up tremendously.

Comment: This is a good idea but the problem is that the eventual size can be really large upto 32 MB and the same thing is going on in parallel for around 20 data channels. So I think the program can run into memory issues.

Comment: @Parag 20*32 MB = 640 MB, not a big deal. Anyway, to me it sounds like you're reading a single file. If so, than use a memory mapped buffer and don't care about re-reading overlapping data.

Comment: @maaartinus I predicted someone would say it so let me put it this way, as of now the I have configured this block size to 32 MB but it can be as large as 256 MB and this is a part of program which itself is memory intensive. So i want to prevent the copying of overlapping data somehow and de-allocate the unnecessary data as soon as possible. As you pointed out i'll have a look into memory mapped buffer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use System.arraycopy.

Our you could use

```
int len = prevArray.length-offset+buffer.length;
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(len);
bb.put(previousByteBuffer);
bb.put(buffer, offset, buffer.length - offset);
```